# Is there anyway to stream data over ADB to the mobile device

Tags: android, flutter, adb, mobile-development

I already create mobile apps for a living, but I want to create something for my own use case.

I want to connect a mobile device with USB debugging enabled and stream a video signal via ADB and then intercept and view it using an application.

I think this can also be done by streaming the video over USB and the app can pick up the stream as input from an external "camera".
My question is can this be done with near 0 latency, or low enough to use my phone as a high refresh rate display?
And where do I start (as in how do I send and listen to the data)?

Any and all help appreciated

I already looked into the built in ADB command:
`adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -`

But this does the opposite of what I want. Is there any way to reverse it...

Comment: Do you know [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)? It can do exactly what you want to implement and it is open source... BTW emulating USB device is pretty difficult on Android so simply using adb for forwarding a TCP stream to the PC is much simpler.

Comment: @Robert I just took a look at scrcpy. It's certainly promising. I'll look into how to somehow reverse the TCP stream.

Comment: Rereading your question confuses me, because it is not clear where you want to capture the video and where to display it. Anyway TCP forwarding via adb works in both directions, just check the adb help text.

Comment: @CoDrift do you want to use your device as a display?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano yes, that's the plan. Streaming the display from the PC over ADB or similar and Keeping latency as low as possible. I know one way would be a socket server but I fear that would introduce alot of delay

Comment: Port forwarding seems like an option. Otherwise, you should try something like https://screentimelabs.com/help/faq/connect-to-the-internet-through-usb/ if USB is all you have.

Comment: Droidcam application in playstore is probably something you might wanna look at, it does exactly what you asking for, get inspiration fom that app!